# Javascript static var

Tags: javascript

Besides readability, is there any reason to avoid or not program static variables using this style?

```js
function not_global()
{
    var print;

    (function() {
        var static = value;
        print = function(value) {
            static = value;
        }
    })();
}
```

Comment: that's global, which means you're polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Given that you're declaring the variable in the global namespace, this just seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: `function foo(){}; foo.bar = function(){};` bar here would be a "static" property/variable as it is only accessible by `foo.bar`

Comment: sorry, its within another function

Comment: It's not static - but a normal variable, or a free variable from the IIFE perspective

Comment: @SpencerKillen Please edit your question then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid that style.  It isn't very explicit so it becomes difficult without comments to tell that `print` being exposed outside of the IIFE is intentional.  Instead, I would suggest returning `print` from the function and assigning it there:

```
var print = (function()
{
    var text_log=document.getElementById('text_log_text');

    return function(string)
    {
        text_log.innerHTML+='<br />'+string;
    };
})();
```

Note that polluting the global namespace is discouraged, so really the best answer here is to just not have `print` exposed outside.  This answer assumes you have already thought through that, and either your IIFE is actually nested in another function (so it isn't polluting the global namespace), or you really do want `print` to be global.